# Is this an efficient / appropriate use of a bloom filter?

Tags: python, computer-science, bloom-filter

I have an API from which data comes in, but a lot of it is redundant (can be determined from an id). I have a bloom filter built up with a few million entries to start.

I am using [this library](https://github.com/jaybaird/python-bloomfilter) to handle the implementation.
From my reading online:

> Bloom Filter is a compact data structure for probabilistic representation of a set of variables to ensure whether elements in set are certainly present or **definitely not** present in the set.  [Source](http://qr.ae/RglZcg)

If I have some pseudocode like this

```
newData #some dataset
for row in newData:
    #filter.add() returns True if in set, we want only not in set
    if not filter.add(row.id):
        #do some stuff with fresh data
```

This function will be called every time a set of data comes in, which is about 200 new entries/sec.

Is this an efficient way to use a bloom filter?

Comment: George - what is your criteria for efficiency? Do you actually mean appropriateness/correctness?

Comment: I suspect the errors that are produced by a bloom filter will be the wrong kind for your application. It may incorrectly say that a given ID has been seen before, when it has not been. I think you'd prefer the other kind of error (falsely saying a value has not been seen, when it has been), since that won't make you skip a value you shouldn't (only process a few extra values you could have skipped).

Answer (score 0):

A Bloom filter can, for any given element, give two answers. It can say "I am definitely sure I have never seen this element before" or "I believe I have seen this element before". In the latter case, it may be that the Bloom filter is incorrect (that is, it's saying "I think I've seen this before" when, in fact, it hasn't).

That is, the question it answers isn't "I have never seen this before" but "I think I have seen this before" (there's no way an element it has seen will get the answer "never seen", but there may be cases where it answers "probably seen" for elements it hasn't seen).

That means that the only answer you can rely on being 100% true is "never seen", but you're probably interested in the other case, so you never skip processing a new element and that isn't the guarantee that the Bloom filter gives you.

If the processing is expensive, you could use a Bloom filter as a gate for a more expensive cache lookup.

Pseudocode:

```
if not bloom.seen(element):
  # we have never seen this
  bloom.add(element)
  value = process(element)
  more_expensive_cache.set(element, value)
  return value
else:
  value, seen = more_expensive_cache.lookup(element)
  if not seen:
    value = process(element)
    more_expensive_cache.set(element, value)
  return value
```